# MySql: Can I Create array using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am Using Mysql DB. my question is : can i create array using sql?
if Yes then how and how to populate this array with output of following query -- "Select column_name1 From tableName".
  Help me, Thanks in Advance

Comment: SQL is the **query** language used to get data out of a database. The result of a query could be stored in an array by a separate **programming** language, but you'd need to specify which one that would be.

Comment: yes, you can. RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php for one way of going about it.

Comment: You are not even mentioning the language you want to use. You can not create an array with MySql only.

Comment: i am not using any programming language. I have to write stored procedure and their i have to do something as i said in my problem.

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays by itself, but you can use cursors to traverse row sets in your stored procedures

Comment: Specifically what are you trying to do? Your question is too broad. Please add more details and/or be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, MySQL **does not support arrays** by itself. That kind of structures are supported by other programming languages (like PHP, Java, Python, etcetera) and you can write a program capable of connecting to a MySQL database, read data from it and populate arrays (I think PostgreSQL supports an array data type, but I'm not sure).

What you can do is use cursors in a stored procedure to retreive data from a query and store it into variables.

Example:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure my_procedure()
begin
    declare value varchar(100);
    declare done int default false;
    declare cur cursor for
        select column_name1 from your_table;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
    open cur;  -- This line will open the row set and place the cursor
               -- on the first row.
    loop_data: loop
        fetch cur into value; -- This line will fetch the current row
                              -- into the variable and move the cursor
                              -- to the next row.
        if done then          -- If there are no more rows in the
            leave loop_data;  -- row set, the loop is terminated here
        end if;               -- and the execution moves to the next
                              -- instruction after "end loop;"
        -- do whatever you need to do with the retrieved value
    end loop;
    close cur;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

If you want to use an array in a high level programming language, you can do it using the appropriate methods. Here's an example using Java (read [The Java tutorials: JDBC Database access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial) for more info):

```
public class SomeClass {
    /*
      Retrieve data from a database and return an array with it.
      Parameters:
       - conn: Connection to the database. 
     */
    public String[] getValues(Connection conn) {
        String[] ans = new String[10];
        int i;
        try(
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                               "select column_name1 from your_table limit 10"
                           );
        ) {
            rs.beforeFirst();
            i = 0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                ans[i] = rs.getString("column_name1");
                i++;
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            // Code to handle the SQL exception
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

---

**References:**

- [MySQL reference manual: Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an variable to simply `select` your row values into a string. Not precisely an array, but it allows you to store all your values into a single variable:

```
-- load test data
create table tableName (column_name1 varchar(5));
insert into tableName values
  ('abcde');
insert into tableName values
  ('fghij');
insert into tableName values
  ('klmno');
insert into tableName values
  ('pqrst');
insert into tableName values
  ('uvwzy');
insert into tableName values
  ('z');

-- build "array"
set @array := '';
select @array := concat(@array,column_name1) as array
from tableName;
select @array;
```